# After successful login ajax data are transferred but jquery script inside of ajax request doesn't execute

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

my problem is that ajax get's right response from php login script but it doesn't execute the script inside of success function, I tried putting alert inside of it and that worked well but my sweet alert doesn't do anything. *note - php registration script work's the same way and sweet alert executes, so I wonder why login does not. Thank's for any kind response and here is the code: 
jquery ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#submitReg").click(function () { //this part work's fine
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var confpassword = $("#confpassword").val();
    if (email == '' || password == '' || confpassword == '') {
        swal({
            type: "error",
            timer: 10000,
            showConfirmButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: "OK",
            confirmButtonColor: "#f4511e",
            title: "Prosím vyplňte všetky polia!"
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax("./php/register.php", {
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                email: email,
                password: password,
                confpassword: confpassword
            },

            success: function ($data) {
                var controlNumber = $data;
                // alert(controlNumber);
                if (controlNumber == 1) {
                    swal({
                        type: "success",
                        timer: 10000,
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "OK",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#f4511e",
                        title: "Registrácia prebehla úspešne."
                    });
                    $('#registerme')[0].reset();
                    $('#result').hide();
                    $('#divCheckPasswordMatch').hide();
                }
                else if (controlNumber == 0) {
                    swal({
                        type: "error",
                        timer: 10000,
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "OK",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#f4511e",
                        title: "Mail už bol zaregistrovaný."
                    });

                }
                else if (controlNumber == 5) {
                    swal({
                        type: "error",
                        timer: 10000,
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "OK",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#f4511e",
                        title: "Niektoré polia ostali nevyplnené."
                    });
                }
                else if (controlNumber == 6) {
                    swal({
                        type: "error",
                        timer: 10000,
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "OK",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#f4511e",
                        title: "Vaše meno / heslo obsahuje neplatné znaky!"
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert(controlNumber);
                }

            }
        })
    }
});
/* this part doesn't work */
$("#loginbtn").click(function () {
    var login = $("#login").val();
    var loginPass = $("#loginPass").val();
    if (login == '' || loginPass == '') {
        swal({
            type: "error",
            timer: 10000,
            showConfirmButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: "OK",
            confirmButtonColor: "#f4511e",
            title: "Prosím vyplňte všetky polia!"
            /* this script isn't showing */
        });
    } else {
        $.ajax("./php/login.php", {
            method: 'POST',
            data: {
                login: login,
                loginPass: loginPass
            },

            success: function ($data) {
                var loginResponse = $data;
                // alert(loginResponse);
                if (loginResponse == 14) {
                    swal({
                        type: "success",
                        timer: 10000,
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "OK",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#f4511e",
                        title: "Prihlásenie prebehlo úspešne."
                    });
                    $('#loginME')[0].reset();
                }
                else if (loginResponse == 10) {
                    //alert(loginResponse);
                    swal({
                        type: "error",
                        timer: 10000,
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "OK",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#f4511e",
                        title: "Something went wrong."
                    });

                }
                else if (loginResponse == 11) {
                    //alert(loginResponse);
                    swal({
                        type: "error",
                        timer: 10000,
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "OK",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#f4511e",
                        title: "Something went wrong."
                    });

                }
                else if (loginResponse == 12) {
                   // alert(loginResponse);
                    swal({
                        type: "error",
                        timer: 10000,
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "OK",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#f4511e",
                        title: "Something went wrong."
                    });

                }
                else if (loginResponse == 13) {
                   // alert(loginResponse);
                    swal({
                        type: "error",
                        timer: 10000,
                        showConfirmButton: true,
                        confirmButtonText: "OK",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#f4511e",
                        title: "Something went wrong."
                    });

                }
                else {
                    alert(loginResponse);
                } //neither any of these script above work

            }
        })
    }
});
});
```

php login:

```
session_start(); // work's fine

require_once 'db_connect.php';
require_once 'functions.php';

if (isset($_REQUEST['login']) && isset($_REQUEST['loginPass'])) {

$login = $_POST['login'];
$loginPass = $_POST['loginPass'];

if (empty($login) || empty($loginPass)) {

    echo 10;
    exit();

} else {

    $prep_stmt = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email= ? ";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);

    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $prep_stmt)) {
        echo 11; //something went wrong
        exit();
    } else {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $login);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $hashedPwdCheck = password_verify($loginPass, $row['password']);
            if ($hashedPwdCheck == false) {
                echo 13; // wrong login
                exit();
            } elseif ($hashedPwdCheck == true) {

                $_SESSION['u_id'] = $row['id'];
                $_SESSION['u_email'] = $row['email'];
                $_SESSION['u_admin'] = $row['admin'];
                echo 14; //logged in
                die();

            }
        } else {
            echo 12; // error
            exit();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Too much code. can you narrow down your problematic code snippet?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna yes, sorry for that, I've inserted comments on problematic code

Comment: what type of code you want to execute in return of ajax call?

Comment: what happen when loginResponse == 14 ?? is it gives any console error?

Comment: @Abdul swal (sweet alert) scripts which are in success function

Comment: @MeeraTank it goes to branch when condition equal 14 but does not execute the swal script, and there are no errors and it pretend to be success

Comment: I highly recommend using the promise syntax for $.ajax rather than success/complete one

Comment: issue seems related to other JavaScript libraries or plugin which need to be executed in ajax function. you will need to check it that really make any call? check source code that either it initiate any object at all?

Comment: @Abdul well the library do just exact thing and code execute successfully in code which is above the problematic and both scripts works the same way

Comment: try to put an alert() right after the success callback opening,if this alert doesnt fire, try using the "complete" callback along with success and see if that one is called.

Comment: @razorxan I already tried putting there alert and alert showed, but swal script dont

Comment: so the problem is in the if else condition ?

Comment: @razorxan no it even goes inside of the condition but that script doesn't execute for some reason, also maybe i should mention it reload the page after login

Comment: well the page reloading is probably your problem here

Comment: @razorxan well and what can i do with that ?

Comment: first try to avoid the page reloading so you can be sure about the issue

Comment: @razorxan but how am I supposed to do that ? can jquery do something like this ?

Comment: why are you making an ajax call if you're gonna refresh the page anyway?

Comment: @razorxan I dont want to refresh it, I dont know why but it just happen automatically after login

Comment: because clicking on a submit inside a form fires the submit event which u have to prevent.

Comment: @razorxan well form have no action and all data was passed just by that ajax request, but there is something wrong with it because the login is working only in chrome for some reason, i tried doing it all without ajax and it started working even inside of firefox, I think ill try separating those ajax request function to singe files, one for login script one for register